# how sort listview filled with sqlite by last modified?

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, listview

I'm absolute beginner.
I have a listview filled with sqlite table, I have two questions:

1- How can I sort this listview by last modified item ?

2- How can I make a button on my first page to open last modified item without going to listview !?

Here are my codes:

Its listview -

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// Declare Variables
public static final String  ROW_ID = "row_id";
private static final String TITLE  = "title";
private ListView            noteListView;
private CursorAdapter       noteAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));

    // Locate ListView
    noteListView = getListView();

    // Prepare ListView Item Click Listener
    noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewNoteListener);

    // Map all the titles into the ViewTitleNotes TextView
    String[] from = new String[]{ TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.ViewTitleNotes };

    // Create a SimpleCursorAdapter
    noteAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_zekr, null, from, to);

    // Set the Adapter into SimpleCursorAdapter
    setListAdapter(noteAdapter);
}

// Capture ListView item click
OnItemClickListener viewNoteListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

                                         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                                             // Open ViewNote activity
                                             Intent viewnote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CounterActivity.class);
                                             viewnote.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
                                             startActivity(viewnote);
                                         }
                                     };


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Execute GetNotes Asynctask on return to MainActivity
    new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();

    // Deactivates the Cursor
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.deactivate();

    noteAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    super.onStop();
}


// Create an options menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Menu Title
    menu.add("ذکر جدید")
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.AddNewNoteClickListener)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// Capture menu item click
OnMenuItemClickListener AddNewNoteClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                                                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                                                        // Open AddEditNotes activity
                                                        Intent addnote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditNotes.class);
                                                        startActivity(addnote);

                                                        return false;

                                                    }
                                                };


// GetNotes AsyncTask
public class GetNotes extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {

    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(MainActivity.this);


    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // Open the database
        dbConnector.open();

        return dbConnector.ListAllNotes();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        noteAdapter.changeCursor(result);

        // Close Database
        dbConnector.close();
    }

}
```

}

its my DatabaseConnector :

```
public class DatabaseConnector {
// Declare Variables
private static final String DB_NAME          = "database";
private static final String TABLE_NAME       = "tablenotes";
private static final String TITLE            = "title";
private static final String ID               = "_id";
private static final String NOTE             = "note";
private static final String COUNTS           = "counts";
private static final String LIMITS           = "limits";
private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private SQLiteDatabase      database;
private DatabaseHelper      dbOpenHelper;


public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}


// Open Database function
public void open() throws SQLException {
    // Allow database to be in writable mode
    database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}


// Close Database function
public void close() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
}


// Create Database function
public void InsertNote(String title, String note, String counts, String limits) {
    ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
    newCon.put(TITLE, title);
    newCon.put(NOTE, note);
    newCon.put(COUNTS, counts);
    newCon.put(LIMITS, limits);

    open();
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, newCon);
    close();
}


// Update Database function
public void UpdateNote(long id, String title, String note, String counts, String limits) {
    ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
    editCon.put(TITLE, title);
    editCon.put(NOTE, note);
    editCon.put(COUNTS, counts);
    editCon.put(LIMITS, limits);

    open();
    database.update(TABLE_NAME, editCon, ID + "=" + id, null);
    close();
}


// Delete Database function
public void DeleteNote(long id) {
    open();
    database.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + "=" + id, null);
    close();
}


// List all data function
public Cursor ListAllNotes() {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ ID, TITLE }, null,
            null, null, null, TITLE);
}


// Capture single data by ID
public Cursor GetOneNote(long id) {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, ID + "=" + id, null, null,
            null, null);
}
```

}

thanks in advance.

UPDATE !

Ok, I Created a Column in my table with name of "time"
and I can insert the time as INTEGER to it like this: 20160516100740

So now every Row of table has a time like that, NOW WHAT CAN I DO ?

Update !

Ok, I wrote this inside my list activity (MainActivity.java)
but its not working : (

```
public Cursor listAllSortedNotes() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY time DESC";
    return database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: Ok, Finally finished ! wrote  + " DESC" after TIME ands its works great ! thank to me and MR Alex !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a field in the database which should be a date string (Sample: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`). And when you update the data, update it with current date and time. Then you can use select query to get the recent update data by using

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY datetime (dateColumn) DESC
```

In your case you can do something like this.

```
public Cursor listAllSortedNotes() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY datetime(dateColumn) DESC";
    return database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but where should i put "SELECT*... " Exactly?

Comment: just create a method which return sorted list. Use above query to database to return data

Comment: sorry i don't know  how.

Comment: thank you very much. but can you look at my listview activity please? where exactly should i put this code ? (sorry i'm absolute beginner)

Comment: can i do that without adding a column to my db table ?

Comment: MR Alex I made a progress but still need help !

Comment: Yea man! You must add a new column if you want to do like this.